# Finding an index of array in C

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, indexing

i wanted to write a code which would allow me to find a position of a fist occurence of a letter, this is what i have come up so far. As you can see, what the function returns is actually a value and not the index. Is there a way to find it without simply giving the initial value of index as in the code no.2?

```
char *recFirstPosition(char * source, int letter)
{

     if(*source == letter)
        return *source;

     if (*source =='\0')
      return 0;

     recFirstPosition(++source, letter);
}


char *recFirstPosition(char * source, int letter, int index)
{

     if(*(source+index) == letter)
        return index;

     if (*(source+index) =='\0')
      return 0;

     recFirstPosition(source, letter, ++index);
}
```

Comment: You need index to make this work unfortunately, or some sort of counting mechanism.

Comment: BTW `return *source;` --> `return source;`, `recFirstPosition(++source, letter);` --> `return recFirstPosition(++source, letter);`

Comment: Neither of the functions returns a value for all control paths.

Comment: change to `int recFirstPosition(`.. `return index;` .. `return 0;` --> `return -1;` .. `recFirstPosition(source, letter, ++index);` --> `return recFirstPosition(source, letter, ++index);`

Comment: Please do not correct any faults in the posted code pointed out in comments, unless it was not your actual code.

Comment: First step is to decide whether you want the function to return a char, a pointer, or an index (int)...

Comment: "I wanted to write a code but it does not return what I want". This is not *your code* is it? As commented above, if you want an index position returned the function type cannot be `char*`.

Comment: No, it is what i have come up with. It is my assignment, we were told to use the function type *char.

Comment: So the question should be "return a pointer to the first ocurrence", your own implementation of [`strchr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b34ccac3.aspx).

Comment: If you were told to return `char *`, are you sure you're not supposed to return a pointer to the character in the string rather than an integer index?

Comment: The exact task is to find the first position of a letter in source string by implementing char * recFirstPosition(char * source, int letter) function, so i suppose it is about the index of array under which there is given letter?

Comment: You want `return source+index;`

Comment: It is int letter, as written above.

Comment: does it have to be recursive?

Comment: Yes, i had to do 2 types of the function but im struggling only with recursive version.

Answer (score 1):

Simply detach * from the first return and add return for the recursive call of your first version.

```
char *recFirstPosition(char * source, int letter)
{

     if(*source == letter)
        return source;

     if (*source =='\0')
      return 0;

     return recFirstPosition(++source, letter);
}
```

It will make the code work. Your first version causes a type error.

The following is more readable version than the above:

```
char *recFirstPosition(char *source, char letter)
{
    if (*source == '\0')
        return NULL;
    else if (*source == letter)
        return source;
    else
        return recFirstPosition(++source, letter);
}
```

The above code also changed the type of the second parameter, but is written mostly inspired by several comments (Special thanks to Yuli and Dmitri).

And you may use the function as follows:

```
int main()
{
    char *s = "Hello";
    char *p = recFirstPosition(s, 'l');
    if (p != NULL) {
        int index = p - s;
        printf("%s[%d] = %c\n", s, index, *p);
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: While testing, it prints some number but i dont think that this number is the right posistion :/

Comment: This is the answer. She could also return `NULL` instead of 0 just to make more semantic sense (although 0 does the job)

Comment: @AnnaSobolewska use printf("%s") on the return value of this function and you'll see that it prints from `letter` on

Comment: Oh yes, it actually prints the string from the letter, but still, i need to print an exact position of this letter, right? so i would need a integer value as a result right? not a whole string? :/

Comment: No.. you need to return a pointer to the letter. Basically your assignment is to implement strchr() by yourself and your first code already does that (when you correct the `source*` mistake). If you want the index, you can just printf("%ld", return_vale - source); If you want the letter that it points to, you can printf("%c", *return_value);

Comment: Thank you for your help ! I get it now! :)

Comment: So, what does this code return when the first character in `source` isn't `letter` *or* `'\0'`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think could work. Please test it more since I did not have enough time to work with it
Edit: This return the position of the last occurrence but should give you enough to work with.
Edit2: Updated the function so now it works for

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *recFirstPosition(const char *s, int c, char *find){
    if(s==NULL) return NULL;
    if(*s == '\0') return (c == '\0') ? (char*)s : find;
    if(*s == c) return (char*) s;
    return recFirstPosition(s + 1, c, *s == c ? (char*)s : find);
}


int main ()
{
  char str[] = "This is a sample string";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Looking for the 's' character in \"%s\"...\n",str);
  pch=recFirstPosition(str,'s', NULL);
  // Uncomment the while loop to get all instances positions  
  //while (pch!=NULL)
  //{
    printf ("found at %d\n",pch-str+1);
  //  pch=recFirstPosition(pch+1,'s',NULL);

  //}
  return 0;
}
```

output 
`Looking for the 's' character in "This is a sample string"...
found at 4`

Comment: just tested again, looks like the function is returning the position of the last occurrence. Since it's an assignment, I will leave that to you to figure out.

Comment: hint: you just need to modify the recFirstPosition to get only the position of the first occurrence ... also note, I am adding 1 to the position so it starts with 1 ...